# system() takes control of keyboard

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

I'm using C++ on Linux. Whenever I make a system() call in a thread it takes control of the keyboard and I'm not able to exit my program using ctrl+c. The program I'm calling with the system call is an SSH command which shouldn't exit until the main calling program has exited. Thank you

Comment: `system()` doesn't return until the command has completed, so if you're running a long running ssh in it `system()` wouldn't return until it finishes.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're doing, can you show us some code that demonstrates the problem you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the [Fork-exec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork-exec) technique to launch the SSH command as a separate process; then, from the launching process, you can wait for the child to finish with [wait](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?wait%202) or kill it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also invoke your SSH commands via `std::async` and get back a `std::future<T>`, where T is presumably `void`, and then `wait()` (or `get()` ) on it. Additionally, you can create a `std::thread` and call `detach()` on it.